# Getting a “FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/h2/data/odp.mv.db (Permission denied)“” when deploying a JHipster project onto Kubernetes

Tags: java

I am trying to deploy my Jhipster (v5.5.0) project onto Kubernetes (v1.16.3), but the pod keeps failing on an attempt to read the database. I assume its because the /var/lib/h2/data directory is not allowing the user read/write access

Here is my YAML that will create the deployment / pod. I have another YAML that creates the PV and PVC.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: portal
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 25%
      maxSurge: 25%
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: portal
          # for argoCD
          image: xxxx.xxxx.com/appliances/kubernetes/portal:temp-test-17
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: portal-config
          # NOTE: the ports.protocol used to be set to TCP, in okd yaml. TCP is the default, so we no longer set it.
          ports:
          - name: http
            containerPort: 8080
          - name: https
            containerPort: 8443
          # resources:
          #   requests:
          #     cpu: 1
          #     memory: 1Gi
          #   limits:
          #     memory: 4Gi
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: "0.5"
              memory: "2048Mi"
            requests:
              cpu: "0.1"
              memory: "64Mi"
          # an image pull policy of IfNotPresent is useful when docker is less available, but requires updating tags during development more often. Originally was "Always"
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          volumeMounts:
            # NOTE: if we use SSL, we will need a 'keystores' volume mount
            # - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/java.io/keystores
            #   name: keystore-volume
            # Volume mount for the database files. Stored on a PV so we can upgrade without removing stored DB data.
            - mountPath: /var/lib/h2/data
              name: portal-db-vol01

          # DEBUG USE ONLY - run as root with elevated permissions. 
          securityContext:
            # allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
            # capabilities: {}
            # privileged: false
            runAsNonRoot: true
            runAsUser: 950

      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred-nexus

     # Monitor for future clean deployment: make sure it doesnt create 2 pvcs
      volumes:
      - name: xxx-db-vol01
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: xxxx-db-pvc-volume01
      # terminationGracePeriodSeconds - we allow 30 seconds for DB cleanup
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
```

Here's the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not open file nio:/var/lib/h2/data/odp.mv.db [1.4.200/1]
    at org.h2.mvstore.DataUtils.newIllegalStateException(DataUtils.java:950)
    at org.h2.mvstore.FileStore.open(FileStore.java:179)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.<init>(MVStore.java:381)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore$Builder.open(MVStore.java:3579)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine$Store.open(MVTableEngine.java:170)
    ... 51 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/h2/data/odp.mv.db (Permission denied)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:124)
    at org.h2.store.fs.FileNio.<init>(FilePathNio.java:43)
    at org.h2.store.fs.FilePathNio.open(FilePathNio.java:23)
    at org.h2.mvstore.FileStore.open(FileStore.java:153)
    ... 54 common frames omitted
```

And here's something I threw into the Dockerfile in order to force this to work, but it seems like the .../h2/data directory is not getting the right permissions

```
USER root

RUN mkdir -p /var/lib/h2/data
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/lib/h2

RUN useradd -d /home/user -m -s /bin/bash user
USER user
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your /var/lib/h2/data to something like /usr/share/..., and make sure your image has more permissions on /var/lib (such as 777)